# Convert String to date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I am facing an issue where a date field was maintained as varchar in Mysql. Users have input dates in different formats e.g :

```
1990/02/22
22/02/1990
22-02-1990
02/22/1990
```

I need to convert these into one date format dd-mm-yyyy. Is there a clean way to do this? I am  using phpmyadmin and when I try:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(cust_dob, 'dd-mm-yyyy') from my_table;
```

I am getting 00-00-0000 for all the fields. Anyone knows what I should do?

Comment: Do you have full access to the table?  I would suggest taking the time to create a date field and run a series of queries to update the field using the varchar field as source.  I don't think a function will ever be able to do what you want especially when you have something like 22/02/1990 and 02/22/1990.  How would the function know what was intended?

Comment: @Robbert Not to mention that it is not possible to remove the ambiguity of 01/02/1990. Is it February or January?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question, I guess you are about to maintain/retrieve data from an dataset which is not organise, not format or it is collect from many source. So the main problem you are facing is **data normalisation.**

I think you could do the following thing:

- update your data to the same format X-Y-Z by replace '/' with '-' 
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

> ```
> mysql> SELECT REPLACE('31/12/2013', '/', '-');
>         -> 'www.mysql'
> ```

- re-arrange data to a unified form, such as 'dd-mm-yyyy'. this is the **most complex** since on your example data, there are **no clue to know if they are format month/day or day/month**. If you did not know it either, I think can make a **guess** *(you can guess can base on data localisation, probability of most data or data itself like field with number > 12 definitely is day)*. By making guess, you are ready to accept **error rate**, update it lately when incorrect data found.
- normalisation data by substring and join it back in order
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

> mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
>
> ```
>     -> 'www.mysql'
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
>
> ```
>     -> 'mysql.com'
> ```

- after everything done, simply use select

> STR_TO_DATE(cust_dob, 'dd-mm-yyyy') from my_table;
>   
>   Note: I guess a programming language like python can make thing become easier. give it a try.

Hope this can help and sorry about my bad English